# Failing to retrieve a single record from a prepopulated SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I know this kind question has been around, and there is already valid answers but none of them worked for me (maybe i have used them wrongly) ..i want to retrieve a single value from Column `"DATABASE_CHILD_24"` which corresponds to `DATABASE_ID` ("_id") 5 from `DATABASE_TABLE3` ..How can i a achieve that and use it in Mainactivity to get a string ..what i have tried:

Database.java

```
public Cursor getDatabase9() {
        String whereclause = DATABASE_ID + "=" + 1;
        String[] col=new String[]{DATABASE_CHILD_24};
        Cursor c= mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE3, col,whereclause, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.moveToPosition(1);
            return c;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

MainActivity.Java

```
 mDatabase = new Database(this);
        mDatabase.open();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase9();
        id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_24));
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

but i get exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.ac.iav.menunaviagtion/ma.ac.iav.menunaviagtion.AboutUs}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
```

, how to do it correctly? thanks

**SECOND PROBLEM** 
i want to be able to retrive a lot of values from one column=column1 (e.g. id1= value 1 from row1column1 ; id2=value2 row 2column1 ..)

what i have tried:
 Database.Java

```
public Cursor getDatabase11() {
    String[] col=new String[]{DATABASE_CHILD_24};
    return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE3, col,null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
mDatabase = new Database(this);
mDatabase.open();
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase11();
cursor.moveToFirst();
id = cursor.getString(0);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

i only get the first value from the column ..how to do what i have explained ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `c.moveToPosition(1);` with `c.moveFirst();`  
The positions are zero based so `c.moveToPosition(1);` will move to the 2nd position which does not exist.  
Although this `c.moveFirst();` would make sense in your `MainActivity` code just after

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase9();
```

try this:

```
mDatabase = new Database(this);
mDatabase.open();
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase9();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_24));
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    slogan.setText(id);
}
```

for the 2nd if you want 3 ids without a loop:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   id = cursor.getString(0);
   // your code here
}

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   id = cursor.getString(0);
   // your code here
}

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   id = cursor.getString(0);
   // your code here
}
```